# Как переключить класс в навбаре по ховеру?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

По умолчанию первой ссылке в навбаре задан класс active, мне нужно при наведении на другую ссылку этого же навбара передать этот класс ей, и убрать с предыдущей выделенной, как решить такую тривиальную задачу?

```
<ul>
 <li><a class="active">link1</a></li>
 <li><a>link2</a></li>
 <li><a>link3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На выбор:

- [hover()](https://api.jquery.com/hover/)
- [mouseenter()](https://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/)

**Javascript**

```js
document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(function(el) {
  el.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
    document.querySelector('a.active').classList.remove("active");
    this.classList.add("active");
  });
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a class="active">link1</a></li>
  <li><a>link2</a></li>
  <li><a>link3</a></li>
</ul>
```

**Jquery**

```js
$("a").on("mouseenter", function() {
  $("a").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a class="active">link1</a></li>
  <li><a>link2</a></li>
  <li><a>link3</a></li>
</ul>
```